# _root_logger_handlers_backup = _root_logger.handlers.copy() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'?

Tags: python

```
import coremltools

labels = 'flower-labels.txt'
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('oxford102.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt'), image_input_names='data', class_labels='class_labels.txt')

coreml_model.save('FlowerClassifier.mlmodel')
```

Comment: I am trying to convert my caffe model into coreml model but I am unable to find what went wrong I spend by whole day and could not able to find the sution please help this error is coming on terminal

Comment: please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask there isnt anything to go on in this question

Comment: Yes this problem is occuring when I am converting my caffe model to core ml model and running the command on terminal please help ? Also tell what is not clear

Comment: For one, you're not asking a question. Then, you provide code that's neither formatted as code nor is it a [mcve]. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: You can [edit] your question to clarify it, which is better than putting additional required info into comments.

Comment: What is your Python version? Can you paste the output of `sys.version` in your question.

Comment: @lllrnr python version is 2.7 which is default one in mac

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the Python version you're using is outdated and not compatible with the latest coremltools.
If updating Python is not an option, you can also try installing an old coremltools version and then run your script again:

```
pip uninstall coremltools       
pip install coremltools==4.0
```

This one worked for me (had the same problem with Python 2.7).

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) for older python 2.7 says that lists do not have copy method.
You should update to the latest python version.

In fact https://pypi.org/project/coremltools/ page itself mentions it supports Python 3.5 onwards.